# Pre-define device number (/dev/video)

Tags: 20.04, devices, lsusb, device-name

having some capture device, it listed with lsusb Bus 002 Device 002: ID 32ed:3200 ezcap ezcap CAM LINK 4K
but its device value changes from time to time, so I need to change cap (j) /dev/video  pretty often.

cv::VideoCapture cap(2);

Is there a way to pre-define the device ?

Comment: how to get everything you needed?
I know only this output                                                                                                    No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: You're well behind on security fixes/upgrades; so I'll suggest applying security fixes asap. This shows the [release of 20.04.5](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/) but installed systems upgraded **before** that date, and your system hasn't had security fixes since before then! and a fully upgraded system no longer reports itself as 20.04.5 either!

Comment: I just need to set dev0-1-2-3 (any) to my hdmi capture card :)
how can I make it?
IRC folks told me that udev rule linux is the way

Comment: FYI:  Link you provided on IRC shows only 3rd party sources (PPA) that don't provide support for *focal* or 20.04 that I can see.  ie. I'd fix https://justpaste.it/b7x91 and then apply security fixes first.  Please add additional details to your question (this is a Q&A site and not a forum; ie. answers will be to your question above; not to comments made about it)

Comment: I fixed ppas and updates, what should be done next?

Comment: ps:  If you get it fixed with help of [sarnold](https://askubuntu.com/users/33812/sarnold) (https://launchpad.net/~seth-arnold) etc, feel free to write your own answer (optionally give thanks to Seth, & if helpful use links that were helpful, but write what worked for you!)

Answer (score 0):

Just passed a little further:

I was able to use `udevadm` control script to make symlink for my device.

But still there is no static name for my device, its number value changes after unplugging the device or pc reboots

I'd like to thank https://askubuntu.com/users/33812/sarnold for his kind support

Comment: This question would be more useful if you gave details on the script & what you did, and what it achieved (*for future readers here*). FYI:  I removed references to me (*I didn't help with regards your question; my only involvement was with the lack of upgrades you'd installed due to unsupported-3rd-party PPAs; details not specific to your question here*)

Comment: I would post the script, but cant find commands as can not find proper logs for IRC

Comment: ACK, yeah I forgot about that.  I brought up your *discovery* (once I'd confirmed) with ubuntu-IRC & I believe they *kicked it* & thus https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2023/07/26/%23ubuntu.txt etc, but what was missed will be missed.  Whilst we have our own copies of what was seen, no globally *logged* copy exists for all sorry.  Your command history should give some clues.